# UIImagePickerController allows selecting square images. But how can I make it 16:9?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I setted up UIImagePickerController and added code:

```
imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
```

This allows user to crop images, but with 1:1 ratio only.

But, I want to crop the image with ratio 16:9, not 1:1. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but you can't change the ratio of default image picker. so you need to use the other third party library. I'm using the below library to manage cropper so you can use it.
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/alcameraviewcontroller.

Here is the code to manage the cropper ratio.

```
func addImagePickerOnController(callBack: @escaping(_ image:UIImage)-> ()) {
    var croppingParameters: CroppingParameters {
        return CroppingParameters(isEnabled: true, allowResizing: true, allowMoving: true, minimumSize: CGSize(width: 60, height: 60))
    }

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Choose Image", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { action in
    }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default) { action in
        let cameraVC = CameraViewController(croppingParameters: croppingParameters, allowsLibraryAccess: false, allowsSwapCameraOrientation: true, allowVolumeButtonCapture: true) { [weak self] image, asset in
            if (image != nil){
                callBack(image!)
            }
            self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        self.present(cameraVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    let galleryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default) { action in
                let libraryViewController = CameraViewController.imagePickerViewController(croppingParameters: croppingParameters) { [weak self] image, asset in
                    if (image != nil){
                        callBack(image!)
                    }
                    self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

                self.present(libraryViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    alertController.addAction(cameraAction)
    alertController.addAction(galleryAction)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true)
}
```